# Y axis level need to be moved little left in dc.js chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am drawing charts using dc.js.The following is a frequency VS Day Chart[image: The following is a frequency VS Day Chart]

I am using the following line to generate the titles:

```
..something.yAxisLabel("Frequency").xAxisLabel('Day');
```

But the problem is as you see when the frequency is so large the Y axis title is colliding with the frequency numbers. So is there any simple way to move the Y axis title left?

Comment: If you could provide a runnable simplest test case of the code that reproduces your problem, that would make it easier to assist. =)

Comment: Lacking code to test with, I'd suggest providing a numerical argument as the second argument to your call to `yAxisLabel()`  e.g. `..something.yAxisLabel("Frequency", 35).xAxisLabel('Day');`

Comment: yAxisLabel("Frequency", 35). it takes the chart to right only but the label of y axis also moves along with the chart. So no improvement

Comment: Alrighty, well, without a simple test case from you, I can't help much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout of auxiliary elements such as axes and legends is not completely automatic in dc.js; use `.margins()` to adjust where necessary.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#marginsmargins

It would be great to figure this out automatically but it is difficult to calculate, and easy to work around, so I guess no one has gotten annoyed enough to submit a fix. :)